# What is the fastest way to read several lines of data from a large file

Tags: c, csv, bigdata, ram, fgets

My application needs to read like thousands of lines from a large csv file around 300GB with billion lines, each line contains several numbers. The data are like these:

```
1, 34, 56, 67, 678, 23462, ...
2, 3, 6, 8, 34, 5
23,547, 648, 34657 ...
...
...
```

I tried `fget` reading file line by line in c, but it took really really really long, even with `wc -l` in linux, just to read all of the line, it took quite a while.

I also tried to write all data to `sqlite3` database based on the logics of the application. However, the data structure is different than the csv file above,  which now has 100 billion lines, with only two numbers each line. I then created two indices on top of them, which resulted a 2.5TB database, while it was 1 TB without indices before. Since the scale of indices are large than data, query has to read the whole 1.5 TB indices, I think it doesn't make any sense to use database method right?

So I would like to ask, what is the quickest way to read several lines within a large csv file with billion lines in C or python. And by the way, is there any formula or something to calculate the time consume between reading file and capacity of RAM.

environment: linux, RAM 200GB, C, python

Comment: You aren't going to get much faster than a sequential read using `fgets()`.  You could try reading large blocks (say 64 KiB) with `fread()` and it might be a little faster, but then you have to analyze the ends of lines, and it gets tricky.

Comment: If you are converting the numbers with `sscanf` you might find it more efficient to use an integer-focussed function.

Comment: For reading, `wc -l` is about the benchmark for speed. Writing to another file, or even to database files will be maybe even 10 times as slow. But: what do you want **to do** with the data?

Comment: @wildplasser Does DB search engine(can I say so?) have to read whole file as well, even if it got the index of line, that it is searching? I thought if it got the index, it will then indicate the physical page of disk, so the DB engine only has to read the indicated portion, no?

Comment: @wildplasser I have to get the data for further calculation

Comment: @WeatherVane you mean convert the string or bytes to integers, and then read the file? can I somehow do this to whole row file as pre-processing? instead of doing it when the program running?

Comment: I mean functions like `atoi` and `strtol` are probably quicker than `sscanf`.

Comment: I think in this case memory mapped file + own parser will be the best solution.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: Your program often works with this huge amount of data and searches for a few thousand lines of it on every run? 
In this case, a one-off pre-processing of the data could be useful. For example, creating a kind of index (e.g. the file offset of each 10K line) or splitting the data into different blocks that are stored as separate files. Once your program is running, it only needs to load and search a much smaller amount of data.

Comment: I beg to differ. Expanding the address space might not be needeed. Just a state machine on getc() will often be sufficient.

Comment: @P__J__ Does the memory mapped file thing need to have RAM space at least equals to the scale of mapped file?

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Yeah, you understood it right. But the thing is, the possibilities of every line got chosen are equal, which means, even we separate the large file into several files, there is still a good chance that the application has to read all the files to get the lines.

Comment: A one-time pre-processing could still be useful then. Since each row contains presumably a maximum amount of numbers, you could convert the csv lines into int-arrays and use a fixed-record format to store the ints in binary format into a separate file. Then, to read line `n`, you can simply calculate the file offset, for example with `line_nr * (sizeof(int) * MAX_NUMBERS_PER_LINE);`. Finally, jump to this offset with `fseeko(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);` and read MAX_NUMBERS_PER_LINE ints. So you only have to read the data you actually want to process. What that work for  you @heisthere?

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements**

- huge csv file, several hundred GB in size
- each line contains several numbers
- the program must extract several thousand lines per run
- the program works several times with the same file, only different lines should be extracted

Since lines in the csv files have a variable length, you would have to read the entire file to get the data of the required lines. Sequential reading of the entire file would still be very slow - even if you optimized the file reading as much as possible. A good indicator is actually the runtime of wc -l, as mentioned already by the OP in the question.

Instead, one should optimize on the algorithmic level. A one-time preprocessing of the data is necessary, which then allows fast access to certain lines - without reading the whole file.

There are several possible ways, for example:

1. Using a database with an index
2. programmatic creation of an index file (association of line numbers with file offsets)
3. convert the csv file into a binary file with fixed format

The OP test shows that approach 1) led to 1.5 TB indices. Method 2), to create a small program that connects the line number with a file offset is certainly also a possibility.  Finally, approach 3 would allow to calculate the file offset to a line number without the need for a separate index file. This approach is especially useful if the maximum number of numbers per line is known. Otherwise, approach 2 and approach 3 are very similar.

Approach 3 is explained in more detail below. There may be additional requirements that require the approach to be slightly modified, but the following should get things started.

A one-time pre-processing is necessary. The textual csv lines are converted into int arrays and use a fixed record format to store the ints in binary format in a separate file. To then read a particular line *n*, you can simply calculate the file offset, e.g. with `line_nr * (sizeof(int) * MAX_NUMBERS_PER_LINE);`. Finally, with `fseeko(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);` jump to this offset and read MAX_NUMBERS_PER_LINE ints. So you only need to read the data that you actually want to process.

This has not only the advantage that the program runs much faster, it also requires very little main memory.

**Test case**

A test file with 3,000,000,000 lines was created. Each line contains up to 10 random int numbers, separated by a comma.

In this case this gave a csv file with about 342 GB of data.

A quick test with

```
time wc -l numbers.csv
```

gives

```
187.14s user 74.55s system 96% cpu 4:31.48 total
```

This means that it would take a total of at least 4.5 minutes if a sequential file read approach were used.

For one-time preprocessing, a converter program reads each line and stores 10 binary ints per line. The converted file is called 'numbers_bin'. A quick test with access to the data of 10,000 randomly selected rows:

```
time demo numbers_bin
```

gives

```
0.03s user 0.20s system 5% cpu 4.105 total
```

So instead of 4.5 minutes, it takes 4.1 seconds for this specific example data. That is more than a factor of 65 faster.

**Source Code**

This approach may sound more complicated than it actually is.

Let's start with the converter program. It reads the csv file and creates a binary fixed format file.

The interesting part takes place in the function pre_process: there a line is read in a loop with 'getline', the numbers are extracted with 'strtok' and 'strtol' and put into an int array initialized with 0.  Finally this array is written to the output file with 'fwrite'.

Errors during the conversion result in a message on stderr and the program is terminated.

**convert.c**

```
#include "data.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void pre_process(FILE *in, FILE *out) {
    int *block = get_buffer();
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t line_capp = 0;

    while (getline(&line, &line_capp, in) > 0) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        memset(block, 0, sizeof(int) * MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE);

        char *token;
        char *ptr = line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((token = strtok(ptr, ", ")) != NULL) {
            if (i >= MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE) {
                fprintf(stderr, "too many elements in line");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            char *end_ptr;
            errno = 0;
            long val = strtol(token, &end_ptr, 10);
            if (val > INT_MAX || val < INT_MIN || errno || *end_ptr != '\0' || end_ptr == token) {
                fprintf(stderr, "value error with '%s'\n", token);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            ptr = NULL;
            block[i] = (int) val;
            i++;
        }
        fwrite(block, sizeof(int), MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE, out);
    }
    free(block);
    free(line);
}


static void one_off_pre_processing(const char *csv_in, const char *bin_out) {
    FILE *in = get_file(csv_in, "rb");
    FILE *out = get_file(bin_out, "wb");
    pre_process(in, out);
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: convert <in> <out>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    one_off_pre_processing(argv[1], argv[2]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Data.h**

A few auxiliary functions are used. They are more or less self-explanatory.

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NUM_LINES 3000000000LL
#define MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE 10

void read_data(FILE *fp, uint64_t line_nr, int *block);
FILE *get_file(const char *const file_name, char *mode);
int *get_buffer();

#endif //DATA_H
```

**Data.c**

```
#include "data.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_data(FILE *fp, uint64_t line_nr, int *block) {
    off_t offset = line_nr * (sizeof(int) * MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE);
    fseeko(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
    if(fread(block, sizeof(int), MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE, fp) != MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "data read error for line %lld", line_nr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

FILE *get_file(const char *const file_name, char *mode) {
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen(file_name, mode)) == NULL) {
        perror(file_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}

int *get_buffer() {
    int *block = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE);
    if(block == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return block;
}
```

**demo.c**

And finally a demo program that reads the data for 10,000 randomly determined lines.

The function request_lines determines 10,000 random lines. The lines are sorted with qsort. The data for these lines is read. Some lines of the code are commented out. If you comment them out, the read data is output to the debug console.

```
#include "data.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


static int comp(const void *lhs, const void *rhs) {
    uint64_t l = *((uint64_t *) lhs);
    uint64_t r = *((uint64_t *) rhs);
    if (l > r) return 1;
    if (l < r) return -1;
    return 0;
}

static uint64_t *request_lines(uint64_t num_lines, int num_request_lines) {
    assert(num_lines < UINT32_MAX);
    uint64_t *request_lines = malloc(sizeof(*request_lines) * num_request_lines);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_request_lines; i++) {
        request_lines[i] = arc4random_uniform(num_lines);
    }
    qsort(request_lines, num_request_lines, sizeof(*request_lines), comp);

    return request_lines;
}


#define REQUEST_LINES 10000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: demo <file>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct stat stat_buf;
    if (stat(argv[1], &stat_buf) == -1) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    uint64_t num_lines = stat_buf.st_size / (MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE * sizeof(int));

    FILE *bin = get_file(argv[1], "rb");
    int *block = get_buffer();

    uint64_t *requests = request_lines(num_lines, REQUEST_LINES);
    for (int i = 0; i < REQUEST_LINES; i++) {
        read_data(bin, requests[i], block);
        //do sth with the data, 
        //uncomment the following lines to output the data to the console
//        printf("%llu: ", requests[i]);
//        for (int x = 0; x < MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE; x++) {
//            printf("'%d' ", block[x]);
//        }
//        printf("\n");
    }

    free(requests);
    free(block);
    fclose(bin);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Summary**

This approach provides much faster results than reading through the entire file sequentially (4 seconds instead of 4.5 minutes per run for the sample data). It also requires very little main memory.

The prerequisite is the one-time pre-processing of the data into a binary format. This conversion is quite time-consuming, but the data for certain rows can be read very quickly afterwards using a query program.

Comment: Rather than tokenize then convert with `token = strtok(ptr, ", ")) != NULL) { ... 
            long val = strtol(token, &end_ptr, 10);`, just use `strtol()` and then walk though `end_ptr` to find next integer.  `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; memset(block, 0, sizeof(int) * MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE);` not really needed.

Comment: Depends. I agree, if the input data can be trusted absolutely. Your approach would probably even increase the conversion speed. But I don't know much about the input data, except what was written in the question. Maybe there are less values in a row than MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_LINE, then the remaining values for constructing a line are at least initialized with 0 (memset). If there is a numerical value that is smaller than long, but outside the range -INT_MIN/+INT_MAX (for example, 2150000000), the program issues an error message "Value error with '2150000000'" and terminates execution.

Comment: Personally, I even would tend to include even more checks :-)
Considering that the conversion only takes place once, this way you can be sure that you have valid, consistent data. But as mentioned before, I know too little about the input data and additional requirements/restrictions.

Comment: Hey, thanks a loooot for your answer, sorry that my laptop was broken so I did not answer in time. This is a very good idea, but would it work if some of the raw data have just 2 items in a row while some have million in a row?

Comment: Would it help, if the huge file is seperated to several subfiles, or even use the huge file directly, and use MangoDB to do that?

Comment: If the number of elements in the rows is massively different, I would rather recommend approach 2 from the answer. Otherwise, you would create an unnecessarily large file. This would create an index file with byte-offsets to the individual lines. From the index file you can then quickly find out where exactly the desired line is located, and it can be read similar to approach 3. Approach 2 should also be very efficient, so much faster than reading the whole file sequentially.